# How can I find the correct disk number of the hard drive installed in the computer?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-cloning

I installed a new Kingston nvme m.2 ssd to my hp 15da2014TX laptop. My old drive is an HDD. Both drives are 1TB.

I want to clear the Kingston drive but, I am afraid to do it because I can't differentiate between HDD and SSD, because I might clear the wrong drive.

It shows the Kingston drive as disk 0 in disk management.[image]

In CMD however, I can't tell for sure if disk 0 is the Kingston drive which I am going to clear. ( I have heard that disk 0 is assigned to the drive which has the operating system installed, in this case the HDD, which I do not want to clear)[image]

How can I confirm which disk is which correctly. I am not an advanced user, so please forgive me if this is a basic dumb question.

Answer (score 0):

Disk1 (C) is two-thirds full, and Disk0 (E) is empty, so they
should be easy to distinguish.

I hope you do not intend to kill Disk1, since it contains Windows.

If you're unsure which is the SSD and which is the HDD, install
a hardware listing product such as
[Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy/download)
which will give all the details about your disks.

Comment: I wasn't sure so I removed the nvme and turned the computer on. Disk 1 which has 6144Kb free is the HDD. Thank you for the suggestion.